# How do I plot multiple variables with pre-computed summary statistics using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to store pre-computed summary statistics for multiple variables and to use them to create both a side-by-side (dodge) bar plot using ggplot and then a faceted side-by-side plot with a third variable.

I'd like to create two plots.

As an example, first, I want to compare y1 and y2 using a side-by-side bar plot for these data:

```
x <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
y1 <- c(24, 26, 31, 19)
y2 <- c(16, 22, 33, 29)
```

Then, I want to have the appearance of a facet wrapped side-by-side bar plot with these data:

```
x <- c("A","B","C","D")

y1_facet1 <- c(78, 7, 9, 6)
y2_facet1 <- c(67, 10, 15, 8)

y1_facet2 <- c(77, 7, 9, 7)
y2_facet2 <- c(70, 9, 13, 8)
```

Any help anyone can offer would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to work with ggplot2 if you reshape your data into longer format first. Here I use `tidyr::pivot_longer(-x)` to take all the columns that aren't `x` and combine them into pairs of `name` (ie source column) and `value`. Then we can map those to different groups using `group`/`fill`/`color` etc. -- simplest here to use `fill` to establish what the separate bars should be, and how they should be distinguished in fill based on which series they relate to.

```
library(tidyverse) # uses ggplot2, dplyr, tidyr
x <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
y1 <- c(24, 26, 31, 19)
y2 <- c(16, 22, 33, 29)
data1 <- data.frame(x, y1, y2) %>%
  pivot_longer(-x)
plot1 <- ggplot(data1, aes(x, value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())


x <- c("A","B","C","D")
y1_facet1 <- c(78, 7, 9, 6)
y2_facet1 <- c(67, 10, 15, 8)
y1_facet2 <- c(77, 7, 9, 7)
y2_facet2 <- c(70, 9, 13, 8)
data2 <- data.frame(x, y1_facet1, y2_facet1, y1_facet2, y2_facet2) %>%
  pivot_longer(-x) %>%
  separate(name, c("name", "facet"))
plot2 <- ggplot(data2, aes(x, value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  facet_wrap(~facet)

library(patchwork)
plot1 + plot2 +  plot_layout(guides = "collect")
```

[image]

Or you could combine the data first for one plot. If you want to adjust the facet order, you could convert the facet variable into a factor and control its ordering using `forcats` that is also loaded with `tidyverse`.

```
data3 = bind_rows(data1 %>% mutate(facet = "facet0"), data2)
ggplot(data3, aes(x, value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  facet_wrap(~facet)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! Awesome and detailed answer!